# Content from ms word pasting to ck,tiny mce,textbox is not showing up

Tags: html, ckeditor, tinymce, editor, textboxio

I copying content from ms word and pasting it to any editor like ck editor , tiny mce , textbox io , is not showing up in editor when i paste from ms word , any possibility to show content by copying from ms word ? because thousands of content is on ms word and want to feed particularly points in website

Comment: ckeditor offers a plugin for this. https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/pastefromword

Comment: (i)5+√2          (ii)3-5√3           (iii)2√3-7          (iv) √2+√5

Comment: the question above which i pasted is not showing up in website why